# Operation translation from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I'm trasnslating a code from Matlab to C++, but there are many things that I don't know about Matlab. (I don't have matlab, so i can't test things)

What does `delx=x(k)-x(p)'` is?

Also, what does `list=k+list`does?

`r2=delx.^2+dely.^2` means that the components of r2 are like `r2[i]=delx[i]^2+dely[i]^2`?

The code to exemplify:

```
N=10
fx=zeros(1,N) 
fy=zeros(1,N) 
fpx=zero(N,N);
fpy=fpx; 
for k=1:N-1
    p=k+1:N; 
    delx=x(k)-x(p)'; 
    dely=y(k)-y(p)'; 
    R2=delx.^2+dely.^2;
    list=find(R2<l2)
    if(length(list)>0);
        list=k+list;
        delx=x(k)-x(list)';
        dely=y(k)-y(list)';
        r2=delx.^2+dely.^2;
        flj=12*(1./r2.^7) - 1./(r2.^4)); 
        fpx(list,k)=(flj.*delx); 
        fpy(list,k)=(flj.*dely);     
        fpx(k,list)=-fpx(list,k);
        fpy(k,list)=-fpy(list,k); 
    end
end
fx=sum(fpx); 
fy=sum(fpy);
```

Comment: Translating something from a language you're not familiar with is a difficult task to begin with. If you don't have access to Matlab, then perhaps first get some experience with Octave, which is similar (at a basic level anyway). Also, please look up the Matlab documentation, where you can find the direct answers you're looking for. If something is still unclear, feel free to ask a specific question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you cannot run the original code, you will never know if you did the translation correctly, because you can't compare outputs. I highly suggest you get access to MATLAB for this translation, if this code is to be used for anything mildly important.

Answer (score 1):

`.^` power gives the "element-wise power", so that `C = A.^B` raises each element of A to the corresponding power in B.

from your code `p=k+1:N;` means that p is a slice from `(k+1):N`.

so, `x(k)-x(p)'` means x in index k, minus x[k+1:N] transposed by the operator `'`.

you can test the code at:
https://octave-online.net/
eg:

```
octave:1> x = 1:10
x =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

octave:3> x'
ans =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
```

Comment: Also, `'` is the complex conjugate transpose.

Comment: A' is the linear algebraic transpose of A. For complex matrices, this is the complex conjugate transpose.

Comment: Yes, but in Python, `np.transpose` is the equivalent of MATLAB's `.'`, not `'`; you need the additional call to `np.conjugate` if `x` is complex. This is an important point that is often missed.